# Generate a list of all permutations of matrices under conditions in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, combinations, permutation

I need to generate a list of all permutations of a 3x3 matrix following these conditions in R:

-The only possible values in the first row are c(0,1,2).

-The only possible values in the second row are c(0,1).

-The only possible value in the last row is 0.

Here's a couple examples:

```
0 0 1
0 0 0
0 0 0

1 0 2
0 1 0
0 0 0

2 2 1
1 1 0
0 0 0
```

So I have to generate all the existing matrices satisfying these conditions. I think there are 216 permutations, if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(plyr)
library(magrittr)

res <- 
  expand.grid(
    0:2, 0:2, 0:2,
    0:1, 0:1, 0:1,
    0, 0, 0
  ) %>% 
  as.matrix() %>% 
  alply(1, matrix, nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)

# remove redundant plyr attributes
res <- res[1:length(res)]

res
#> $`1`
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0
#> 
#> $`2`
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0
#> 
#> $`3`
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0

...
```

`expand.grid` creates a data.frame of all combinations of 9 numbers where first three numbers can be from 0 to 2, second three are either 0 or 1, and last three are always 0. So basically it's our needed matrices written in rows. There are indeed 216 of them. Now we just need to turn the rows into 3x3 matrices.
The best approach I was able to find is to convert the dataframe into  matrix and then use `plyr::alply`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure out how to do this in functional programming way, but here's the for loop approach.

```
library(gtools)

x <- permutations(3,3, c(0,1,2),repeats.allowed = TRUE)
y <- permutations(2,3,c(0,1), repeats.allowed = TRUE)

z = list()
length = 1
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(y)){
  z[[length]]  <- (matrix(c(x[i,],y[j,],0,0,0), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE))
   length = length + 1
  }
}

> length(z)
[1] 216
```